# Mirroring UV's not working

Tags: uv

I am trying to get blender to mirror the UV map with the mirror modifier, but the other side is not showing up anywhere in the UV editor.

I'm using Blender 2.93

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn it on, it's in the UV Editor > overlays > Modified edges

[image]